# Не работает \\s для некоторых пробельных символов

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть код:

```
String square = "";
if (title.contains("м²")) {
  String regex = "\\d+([,.]\\d+)?\\s*м²";
    
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(title);
    
  if (matcher.find()) {
    square = matcher.group();
  }
}
```

И есть строки:

```
Апартаменты-студия, 22,8 м², 1/5 эт. 
2-к. квартира, 50 м², 4/5 эт.
```

Код не находит соответствия regex в строках.
Само выражение проверял на сторонних сервисах - находит.

Что может быть?

Comment: Какого типа переменная `title` и что в ней находится? Сделайте [mre], который демонстрирует вашу проблему. В приведенном вами коде нет видимых проблем, но его нельзя запустить, так как нет объявления переменной `title`.

Comment: Проблема НЕ воспроизводится, см. [онлайн демо](https://ideone.com/RxHBJ3) для показанных данных.  Если входная строка `title` читается из файла, _может быть_ проблема с кодировкой (например, у файла Win-Cp1251, а в коде -- UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в каком-то непечатаемом символе. Выглядит как пробел, но пробелом не является.

В режиме отладки из `title` скопировал этот "пробел" в `regex`, и всё заработало.

Comment: Предполагаю, что это [неразывный пробел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Неразрывный_пробел). Вы можете использовать `[\\s\\h]` вместо `\\s`, чтобы учесть разные пробельные символы. Написал [более развернутый ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1516575) на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Такая проблема может возникнуть, если между числом и единицей измерения используется [неразрывный пробел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB).

В соответствии с [документацией Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), класс `\s` (пробельный символ) соответствует регулярному выражению:

```
[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
```

В то время как класс `\h` (горизонтальный пробельный символ) это:

```
[ \t\xA0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000]
```

Чтобы в вашем регулярном выражении учесть неразрывный пробел, используйте комбинацию из двух классов `[\s\h]` вместо обычного `\s`.

Например:

```java
String regex = "\\d+([,.]\\d+)?[\\s\\h]*м²"
```